# What happens when chemical elements are struck by cosmic rays?

Tags: gamma-rays, elements, cosmic-rays

> When struck by cosmic rays, chemical elements in soils and rocks emit uniquely identifiable signatures of energy in the form of gamma rays. These data can help scientists look for geologically important elements such as hydrogen, magnesium, silicon, oxygen, iron, titanium, sodium, and calcium.

I would like to know what exactly happens(in the above block-quote), in detail, when chemical elements are struck by cosmic rays?

Source: https://science.nasa.gov/ems/12_gammarays

Comment: The nuclei get excited, and gamma emission relaxes back to the ground state.

Comment: Or the nuclei undergo fission by spallation which also releases gamma rays...